# Checking presence of attribute with cts:query

Tags: marklogic

`cts:element-query(xs:QName("elm"),cts:and-query(()))` will give all the fragments where the element **elm** is present.

Similarly if I want all documents where an attribute(say **atr**) is present under **elm** what would I have to do?

`cts:element-attribute-value-query()` requires that I pass a value to match against the attribute value. But I want to check only the existence of the attribute irrespective of what value it contains.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by a simple cts:element-attribute-value-query

```
cts:element-attribute-value-query(
xs:QName('element'), xs:QName('attribute'), '*'))
```

In case you have not set wildcarded search true in database, you also need to provide wildcarded enabled search explicitly in cts:element-attribute-value-query

```
cts:element-attribute-value-query(
xs:QName('element'), xs:QName('attribute'), '*', ("wildcarded")))
```

For more details on this you can check [cts:element-attribute-value-query](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:element-attribute-value-query) page

Answer (score 1):

Try using a wildcard. One difference between elements and attributes is that elements can be empty. Attributes can't, so they should always match a wildcard. You may need to enable some character indexes for optimal performance.

```
cts:element-attribute-value-query(
  xs:QName('div'), xs:QName('id'), '*'))
```

Comment: Will it not require checking against the values(although any value would be a match) and hence some time in reading the values?

Comment: @mblakele, surprised to here you say XML Attributes can't be empty.  I think they can.

Comment: They can have the value "". Empty elements are special.

Comment: @mblakele, sure? This returns true: let $xml1 := <test/>
let $xml2 := <test>{""}</test>
return deep-equal($xml1, $xml2) ;-)

Comment: Yes, they compare identically. To me it feels different than `foo=""`.