# How to check the attribute availability in xml?

Tags: xquery, marklogic

How to find the attribute is available or not in particular element?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checking presence of attribute with cts:query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21434099/checking-presence-of-attribute-with-ctsquery)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use XPath that will return your target attribute and convert the result to boolean :

```
boolean(//target_element/@target_attribute)
```

or similar approach but using [`exists()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2010/REC-xpath-functions-20101214/#func-exists) function :

```
exists(//target_element/@target_attribute)
```

<sub>Actually, the context isn't clearly stated in the question, for example, maybe the context element in your case is the target element already, so you don't need `//target_element/` part.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can return all of the attribute names for the target element:

```
//target-element/(@*[1])
```